Multi-Line VirtualBox VM Description From The CLI
How do you put a multi-line description in for a VirtualBox VM from the CLI? ie:
vboxmanage modifyvm My_VM --description="Minimal Centos Linux 9<br/>RAM: 2 GB"

(Yes, I'm trying to script things. No, I'm not using Vagrant (& I don't want too), just plain ol' bash.)
I've tried the above using <br/>, <p></p> and \n and none of them work.

You'll have to put an actual line break in your command. Depending on which command shell you're running this from, it might be either as easy as literally hitting Enter midway through the "quoted text, or outright impossible.
In Bash you can put line breaks within quoted strings, e.g.:

vboxmanage modifyvm My_VM --description="Minimal Centos Linux 9↵
RAM: 2 GB"↵

You can also use its $'...' quoted strings that will expand C-style backslash escapes (before the command is being run, i.e. without the need for VirtualBox to understand them):
vboxmanage modifyvm My_VM --description=$'Minimal Centos Linux 9\nRAM: 2 GB'

or, if you prefer,
br=$'\n'
vboxmanage modifyvm My_VM --description="Minimal Centos Linux 9${br}RAM: 2 GB"


Generally speaking, while HTML tags are a possibility, they're a rare one; even the components that use HTML-ish markup tend to express newlines as literal newlines rather than special tags.
